# Increasing memory usage of simulation of quantum circuits in a "for" loop with Qiskit

Tags: loops, ram, qiskit

I have the following code:

```py
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, transpile
from qiskit_aer import AerSimulator
from qiskit.providers.fake_provider import FakeMumbai
import resource

    
backend = FakeMumbai()
sim = AerSimulator.from_backend(backend)
shot = 1000
num_samples = 1000
for s in range(num_samples):
    qc = QuantumCircuit(4)
    qc.measure_all()
    transpiled_circuit = transpile(qc, sim)
    sim.run(transpiled_circuit,shots=shot)
    print(resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss)
```

where the `resource` part is only to check the memory usage.
As the loop goes on, the memory usage increases. Why?

For this kind of circuit we still talk about few bytes, but I have this problem also for larger circuits, and, in that context, the script terminates.

I have already tried with `del` and `gc.collect()` without results.